# Trying to make a bot leave a server by command

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make the bot leave a server with the ID, Command !leave

I get the error `'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_server'`

Here is my script:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

token = TOKEN HERE

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx, ID):
    toleave = client.get_server(ID)
    await client.leave_server(toleave)
    print("Left Server")

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, discord.py 1.1, `get_server` has been renamed to `get_guild`, and `leave_server` has been moved to `Guild.leave`. So, your code would look something like:

```py
toleave = client.get_guild(ID)
await toleave.leave()
```

Comment: Thanks, It got me passed the first error but now, ```'NoneType' object has no attribute 'leave'```

Comment: Check your id and make sure it's actually valid.

Comment: literally just copied the ID from a test server that the bot is in

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
@commands.command()
  async def leave(self, ctx, *, message=None ):
    guild_id = message
    guild = await self.client.get_guild(int(guild_id))
    channel = guild.system_channel
    await channel.send("Leaving this server due to misuse!")
    await guild.leave()
```

Comment: Please explain your code and why it should work

Comment: @phoenixstudio this was built for a cog, but can be made for a single script bot by changing `@commands.command()` to `@client.command()`.

as for why it should work, just read the `discord.py` documentation bro. [Discord.py Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/api.html)